# Android JSON Parse Getting Array within Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, parsing

Seems like a simple problem, and I know there are multiple questions like this already. I'm trying to get JSON data from an Array within an Array.

I have a JSON Array as follows:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "time": "09:00:00",
        "claim": {
            "date": "2015-08-06",
            "comments": "Some comments"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary Smith",
        "time": "10:00:00",
        "claim": {
            "date": "2015-08-06",
            "comments": "Some comments"
        }
        }
    }
]
}
```

I'm trying to parse all the information out of it, I'm able to get the `name` and `time` but i'm having trouble getting the data out of the `claim` array.

I have view multiple similar problems here on SO but none of their solutions fixed my problem.

Here is my Java Code:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        try {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            JSONArray android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing  JSON items in Variables
                String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);

                //For loop for claims array:
                JSONArray claims = c.getJSONArray(TAG_CLAIM);
                for (int j = 0; j < claims.length(); j++) {
                    JSONObject d = claims.getJSONObject(j);
                    String name = d.getString(TAG_NAME);
                 //other parsing and list view.
```

I'm getting this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value {"date": "2015-08-06","comments": "Some comments"} at claim of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
08-06 12:43:27.436  17586-17586/com.murrion.navigationdrawer W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100)
08-06 12:43:27.436  17586-17586/com.murrion.navigationdrawer W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:588)
```

On this line: `JSONArray claims = c.getJSONArray(TAG_CLAIM);`

I'm not sure what is going wrong, I'd greatly appreciate some help. Thanks

Comment: please learn json's basics ... obviously: `{ .... }` is not an array

Comment: your json format is wrong check it what you posted above is having extra } braces here and also claim is not array its object,so call it from simply from jsonObject

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`claim` is not an array, but another object. If you want it to be an array, it should be something like this:

```
    "claim": [
        "date": "2015-08-06",
        "comments": "Some comments"
    ]
```

(notice the `[` `]` instead of `{` `}`)

If it's meant to be an object, then the code should read:

```
            JSONObject claims = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CLAIM);
```

Comment: your json format is even wrong  In his case it should be {.....his rest object and 
 "claim" : [{
   "date" : "2015-08-06",
   "comments" : "Some comments"
  }
 ]
}

Comment: and in general it will be like this     [{"date":"2015-08-06","comment":"some comments"},{"date":"2015-08-07","comment":"some comments1"}] or  [{"date":"2015-08-06","comment":"some comments"} ] or [] this

Comment: @Naval, The relevant point is that he was attempting to parse an object as an array. After being pointed to that fact, he can fix his code to make it match the json object or the other way around. The answer is not about doing all the work, but pointing the way to the solution.

Comment: ,yeah you are right we have to pointing the way to the solution, the example you have quoted is wrong but explaining the problem and given the solution is correct and you did his whole job by  writing     JSONObject claims = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CLAIM); this line dude even if you see his json that is not right may be typo problem but whole problem start from thier only

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "time": "09:00:00",
        "claim": [

            "date": "2015-08-06",
            "comments": "Some comments"
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Mary Smith",
        "time": "10:00:00",
        "claim": [
            "date": "2015-08-06",
            "comments": "Some comments"
        ]

    }
]
}
```

**Note:** The problem in your json is clearly mentioned in the Error stack trace, which tells you that you are trying to parse the json object(within {...}) as json array(array should be within[...], not {...}). So please try to read the stack trace.

Comment: this json format is also wrong dude  "claim": [
            "date": "2015-08-06",
            "comments": "Some comments"
        ]  this is even not array see my above comment in @Sebastian    this should be like this  within jsonObject             "claim": [{
            "date": "2015-08-06",
            "comments": "Some comments"
       } ]  so you can call this array by name "claim" else remove the the name and its will become jsonarray

Comment: yeah...I have gone through.and understood my mistake. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the Extra } curly braces you json will be like this

```
   {
        "results" :
        [
            {
                "name" : "John Doe",
                "time" : "09:00:00",
                "claim" : 
                {
                    "date" : "2015-08-06",
                    "comments" : "Some comments"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "Mary Smith",
                "time" : "10:00:00",
                "claim" : 
                {
                    "date" : "2015-08-06",
                    "comments" : "Some comments"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
and to parse this json your code like this
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
{
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
        try 
        {
            // Getting JSON Array from URL
            JSONArray android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);    
                // Storing  JSON items in Variables
                String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                String time = c.getString("name");    
                //  for claims  object:
                JSONObject claims = c.getJSONObject(TAG_CLAIM);
                    String date= claims .getString("date");
                    String comments= claims .getString("comments");
                 //other parsing and list view.
             }
         }
         catch(Exception e){}
}
```

as you are saying your json should be like this

```
{
    "results" :
    [{
            "name" : "John Doe",
            "time" : "09:00:00",
            "claim" : [{
                    "date" : "2015-08-06",
                    "comments" : "Some comments"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "name" : "Mary Smith",
            "time" : "10:00:00",
            "claim" : [{
                    "date" : "2015-08-06",
                    "comments" : "Some comments"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and your code like this

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) 
    {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            try 
            {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                JSONArray android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);    
                    // Storing  JSON items in Variables
                    String time = c.getString(TAG_TIME);
                    String time = c.getString("name");    
                    //  for claims  object:
                    JSONArray claims = c.getJSONArray(TAG_CLAIM);
                    for (int j = 0; j < claims.length(); j++) {
                       JSONObject d = claims.getJSONObject(j);
                        String date= d.getString("date");
                        String comments= d.getString("comments");
                     //other parsing and list view.
                     }
                 }
             }
             catch(Exception e){}
    }
```